# Where are Pygame Fonts located on Windows?

Tags: python, text, fonts, pygame

I would like to know where are the pygame Impact font for use it in my own game. If I use `pygame.font.get_fonts()` Impact is in the list.

I navigate to all Python and PyGame folders (Without change anything) and the most similar I found is `font.h`

I'm using Windows 10 with Python 3.7 and PyGame 1.9.4

The path where I looking is `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Include\pygame`

I excepted that the font will be on a pygame folder of `Python37` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fonts available will be system dependent. However, you can get a list of all of the fonts available by calling: `pygame.font.get_fonts()`.

You can load any TrueType font file (*.ttf) with `pygame.font.Font()`. To load the font file myfont.ttf in your project directory simply call `pygame.font.Font("myfont.ttf", size)`. Substitute the path to your file for the first parameter if you have it in a different location. You can use either a relative or an absolute file path.

So I assume there are no fonts pre-saved in a directory.